# Why aren't my CSS media queries working?

Tags: html, css, web, media

I am trying to make a responsive website for desktops, tablets and mobile devices but I am facing some trouble. I created a document called `responsive-Ipad.css` that would work only in Ipads (I set the min-width to 600px) but somehow the css files are affecting the screen content in any device (tablet, mobile or desktop). I have 2 other css files.

1. `style.css` that I use to set the desktop layout,
2. `responsive.css` to set the mobile layout and responsive-Ipad.css for Ipads.

the style.css doesn't have media query
the responsive.css starts with this line code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:420px){
```

and the responsive-Ipad starts with this line code:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px){
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[Image that represents the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpNL9.jpg)

Comment: have you added meta tag <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

Comment: Please make sure that "responsive.css" css file is link to the website

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.css">

Comment: Provide you html code...

Comment: I would suggest you to use bootstrap to reduce your development time and its easily maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

Try using these media queries and add this meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

```css
@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) {
  /* For general iPad layouts */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  /* For portrait layouts only */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  /* For landscape layouts only */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have included your `CSS` (File path should be proper) file properly in your `HTML` page. And for responsive web page you need the below `meta` tag  to be included in your `HTML` page. Just before including your CSS file.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

This will be better if you include these lines in your `HTML` page.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: I did this and nothing. Everytime I add responsive-Ipad.css on HTML's head tag all the other screens (mobile and desktop) get messed up. Somehow it isn't affecting only for Ipad Screens. I added an image so you can see better what's going on. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*
CSS for your media query
*/

@media (max-width:420px){
  
  /*your css for devices that are below 420px*/
}

@media (min-width:600px){
  
  /*your css for devices that are above 600px*/
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive-ipad.css">
  </head>
  
  
  <body>
  <!--HTML Content-->
  </body>
  </html>
```

> Make sure you include all your **css** files into your **HTML** file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did this and nothing. Everytime I add responsive-Ipad.css on HTML's head tag all the other screens (mobile and desktop) get messed up. Somehow it isn't affecting only for Ipad Screens. I added an image so you can see better what's going on. Thanks

Comment: cant' you use bootstrap's `responsive-utility` class. here you can get to know better : https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/